# Заполнение категорий

Tags: php, dle, база-данных

Здравствуйте. Скажите пожалуйста, как заполнить категории в моем сайте [fresh-kino.ru](http://fresh-kino.ru)? А именно "Год выхода", "Режиссер:", "В ролях:" и другие.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь "Дополнительными полями". Создайте поля для этих данных и они будут доступны тэгами [x_fileds] - точно не помню название тэга. Дополнительные поля дополнительную нагрузку на базу данных не несут. Количество запросов при просмотре материала так же останется неизменным.

Answer (score 0):

Метка неверная указана. Решение просто. Либо в файлы писать, либо, что удобнее на мой взгляд, в базу данных. В ней и хранить всю необходимую Вам информацию.